# GPU clocks fixed at minimum

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, clockspeed

I have an Asus Nvidia Geforce GTX 550TI In my system. For some reason, a short time after booting up my PC it's clock rates will drop to their minimums

[image: screenshot]

regardless of the load on the card.

For example, I can run a game a few minutes after booting up and it runs at 60fps no problem for say about 10 minutes, with the clock speeds at their normal values. But then suddenly the clocks drop down to the minimum and even with 100% usage on the GPU they stay there and my framerate drops to ~2fps.

I have MSI afterburner installed which as far as I know is the only non-system program that has control of the GPU clock speeds. But I only use that for fan control and on-screen display. The clocks and voltage are left at their default values

[image: MSI afterburner screenshot].

Once the clock speeds fall to their minimum they stay there until i restart the PC and then the whole process starts again and it works fine for a little while before dropping back down again after a seemingly random amount of time.

Any ideas or help is appreciated.

**Edit:** It does appear to be Afterburner causing it, but strangely only when started with windows. If I uncheck the box to start afterburner with windows and restart then the card runs fine without afterburner running (ignoring the temperature) and then if I open afterburner and apply the fan control it seems to continue to run without any of the previous problems.

Comment: If you don't use Afterburner, for an ASUS card, any change?

Comment: If you are using the fan control to limit the fan speed then it may be that the card is getting too hot. Have you tried disabling the fan control?

Comment: @Ramhound see my edit to the original question

Comment: @Mokubai I don't think it's the temperature, I use the fan control to make sure the temperature is under control as it seems to stay at 30% fan speed without it regardless of temperature. With fan control, the temp is around 35 celsius

Comment: Then it is probably a problem with the MSI software not re-setting itself as the controller for the fan and clocks after the system comes out of the "fastboot" hibernation process. I've seen something similar in the past but can't remember what software it was. If disabling that software fixes the problem then either leave it disabled or see if there is an update from MSI.

Comment: I would either use the ASUS version of this software or don't use it, at all, it's not required